# Identifying level curves which are perpendicular to a particular vector field

Tags: calculus, vectors, curves

In this problem I am given numerous vector field equations (both in 2 and 3 dimensions) and I am being asked which level curve/surface they are perpendicular to. The general process I've been using is to work backwards with the partial derivatives to attempt to recover some function which I can identify. For example one of the vector fields was defined as such;

**F** = $x$**i** + $y$**j**

Knowing that $x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $ as well as $y=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $, reconstructing the level curve (from what I understand) is as simple as finding the corresponding antiderivatives which yield these partials, thus

$0 = \frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{y^{2}}{2}+C$ (Clearly a family of circles)

My issue lies in this vector field:

**F** = $-y$**i** + $x$**j**

I can't find antiderivatives that satisfy this equation and therefore can't identify the level curve the field is meant to be intersecting perpendicularly (Although when graphing it looks a lot like lines which rotate about the origin). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do the line integral of $F = (-y,x)$ around the unit circle. You will get a non-zero answer. So by the fundamental theorem for line integrals, this cannot be the gradient of a function.

Comment: Set up a differential equation which says that the curve you seek is orthogonal to $\mathbf F$. That is, at $(x,y)$, what must its slope be?